# How to change path for homebrew: "config" scripts exist outside your system or Homebrew directories

Tags: installation, homebrew

Goal: install Ruby 2.0.0

Brew Doctor says:

```
Warning: "config" scripts exist outside your system or Homebrew directories. `./configure`
scripts often look for *-config scripts to determine if
software packages are installed, and what additional flags to use when
compiling and linking.

Having additional scripts in your path can confuse software installed via
Homebrew if the config script overrides a system or Homebrew provided
script of the same name. We found the following "config" scripts:

/opt/sm/pkg/active/bin/curl-config
/opt/sm/pkg/active/bin/ncurses5-config
/opt/sm/pkg/active/bin/ncursesw5-config
/opt/sm/pkg/active/bin/pkg-config
/opt/sm/pkg/active/bin/xml2-config
/opt/sm/pkg/active/bin/xslt-config
```

I found the answer here: [Brew doctor gives out warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15225312/brew-doctor-gives-out-warnings)    but don't know how because he didn't tell us how to do it

I need to remove /opt/sm/pkg/active/bin/  from my path.

```
$ echo $PATH 
/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/sm/bin:/opt/sm/pkg/active/bin:/opt/sm/pkg/active/sbin:/Development/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools:/Development/android-sdk-macosx/tools
```

but when I open my file
    touch ~/.bash_profile; open ~/.bash_profile

I get:

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/Development/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools:/Development/android-sdk-macosx/tools
##
# Your previous /Users/john/.bash_profile file was backed up as     /Users/john/.bash_profile.macports-saved_2013-06-06_at_14:30:25
##

# MacPorts Installer addition on 2013-06-06_at_14:30:25: adding an appropriate PATH     variable for use with MacPorts.
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
# Finished adapting your PATH environment variable for use with MacPorts.


[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

Notice the path I'm trying to remove is not in the file, but it's in my path. What do I do??

Comment: Do you know what “sm” is?

Comment: No, I don't. what is sm?

Comment: It’s where whatever it is was installed: `/opt/sm`.

Answer (score 3):

The `/opt/sm` is in the `/etc/profile.d` directory. Open it by entering

```
cd /etc/profile.d
```

in terminal and then

```
 open .
```

Open sm.sh file in text editor and then 
change

```
PATH="${PATH}:/opt/sm/bin:/opt/sm/pkg/active/bin:/opt/sm/pkg/active/sbin"
```

to

```
#PATH="${PATH}:/opt/sm/bin:/opt/sm/pkg/active/bin:/opt/sm/pkg/active/sbin"
```

and then quit and relaunch Terminal. Run `brew doctor` 'Warning' should be gone.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that "sm" comes from [RailsInstaller](http://railsinstaller.org/en), at least in my case.  Following the approach in [this post](https://teamtreehouse.com/forum/brew-doctor-errors-homebrew-help-please), I commented out the line in `/etc/profile.d/sm.sh` and restarted Terminal.  This solved the above `brew doctor` errors.