# Mac Homebrew Warnings: config script exists and non-Homebrew pkg-config in your PATH

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, path, terminal, homebrew

I managed to fix most of the warning but I could not get rid of these ones. I did find something that appears to be a solution [Brew doctor gives out warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15225312/brew-doctor-gives-out-warnings) but I am not able to get rid of the messages. My current .bash_profile is:

```
    # Fix $PATH for homebrew
    homebrew=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin
    export PATH=$homebrew:$PATH
```

and here are the warnings:

Warning: "config" scripts exist outside your system or Homebrew directories.
`./configure` scripts often look for *-config scripts to determine if
software packages are installed, and what additional flags to use when
compiling and linking.

Having additional scripts in your path can confuse software installed via
Homebrew if the config script overrides a system or Homebrew provided
script of the same name. We found the following "config" scripts:

```
/opt/sm/pkg/active/bin/curl-config
/opt/sm/pkg/active/bin/ncurses5-config
/opt/sm/pkg/active/bin/ncursesw5-config
/opt/sm/pkg/active/bin/pkg-config
/opt/sm/pkg/active/bin/xml2-config
/opt/sm/pkg/active/bin/xslt-config
```

Warning: You have a non-Homebrew 'pkg-config' in your PATH:
  /opt/sm/pkg/active/bin/pkg-config

`./configure` may have problems finding brew-installed packages using
this other pkg-config.

Comment: Thanks for asking. I decided to ignore the warning messages until I actually encounter a problem.