# Can't get Homebrew and git to work the way I want them to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, osx-mountain-lion, homebrew

First off, I'm sorry for any silly mistakes on my part. I'm just starting with OneMonthRails, and this is all very new to me. My problem is with Homebrew and git. I'm told that my problem has to do with environmental variables, and I've done enough research to be confident this is correct. Ok, here's the details:

I've tried to install Homebrew, but ran into a snag with Xcode being absent. Was running OSX 10.6.8, and had to upgrade to at least 10.7.x to install the latest Xcode. I upgraded to OSX 10.8.4 and installed Xcode and reran the following line

```
$ ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)"
```

I get the following script:

```
==> Installation successful!
You should run `brew doctor' *before* you install anything.
Now type: brew help
```

I am installing Homebrew so that I can install ImageMagick in order to run the Paperclip gem, so I take the advice of my Terminal about running $ brew doctor.

```
$ brew doctor
```

produces the line

```
Warning: Experimental support for using Xcode without the "Command Line Tools".
You have only installed Xcode. If stuff is not building, try installing the
"Command Line Tools" package provided by Apple.
Warning: Broken symlinks were found. Remove them with `brew prune`:
```

**///long list of broken symlinks///**

```
Warning: An outdated version of Git was detected in your PATH.
Git 1.7.10 or newer is required to perform checkouts over HTTPS from GitHub.
Please upgrade: brew upgrade git
```

I want to know what my git version is so I run the following script:

```
$ git --version
```

and that produces the following line:

```
git version 1.7.9.6
```

I identify where my git is located:

```
$ which git
```

and that brings:

```
/opt/sm/pkg/active/bin/git
```

After some more research, I find out that I can upgrade my git with the following script:

```
$ brew install git
```

The final line of the resulting script is a warning:

```
Warning: This keg was marked linked already, continuing anyway
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/git/1.8.3.2: 1325 files, 28M, built in 45 seconds
```

I verify my git upgrade

```
$ git --version

git version 1.7.9.6
```

sudo think...maybe I need to run upgrade instead of install.

///restart computer///

```
$ brew upgrade git
Error: git-1.8.3.2 already installed
```

hmm... try doctor again

```
$ brew doctor

Warning: Experimental support for using Xcode without the "Command Line Tools".
You have only installed Xcode. If stuff is not building, try installing the
"Command Line Tools" package provided by Apple.

Warning: "config" scripts exist outside your system or Homebrew directories.
`./configure` scripts often look for *-config scripts to determine if
software packages are installed, and what additional flags to use when
compiling and linking.

$ git --version
git version 1.8.3.2
```

YAY! I DID SOMETHING RIGHT! Now to finish with Homebrew so I can move on to installing ImageMagick:

```
$ brew doctor

Warning: Experimental support for using Xcode without the "Command Line Tools".
You have only installed Xcode. If stuff is not building, try installing the
"Command Line Tools" package provided by Apple.

Warning: "config" scripts exist outside your system or Homebrew directories.
`./configure` scripts often look for *-config scripts to determine if
software packages are installed, and what additional flags to use when
compiling and linking.
```

Arrg... I just installed Xcode. How do I install Command Line Tools? And what is this config Warning? I check it on StackOverflow, and it leads me here:
(.../questions/15225312/brew-doctor-gives-out-warnings)

I don't exactly know what I'm doing, so the following is kinda stupid

```
$ $PATH
```

nope

```
$ echo $PATH
```

nothing...

```
$ export PATH=/sm/pkg/active/bin/
```

nothing

```
$ export PATH= /sm/pkg/active/bin/
-bash: export: `/sm/pkg/active/bin/': not a valid identifier
```

(*notice the space after the =*)

I realize just how much I don't know what I'm doing, so I ask for help

```
$ brew help
-bash: brew: No such file or directory
```

uh oh...

```
$ brew doctor
-bash: brew: No such file or directory
```

I think I broke my computer, guys. What should I do??? I need to get Homebrew functioning so that I can install the ImageMagick image processor and use the Paperclip gem in Rails.

:((

Comment: stack-overflow-tip: you can format as code instead of bold.

Comment: Ok, some control questions. WTF is '/opt/sm/pkg' and '/sm/pkg/'?

Comment: And a quick fix - you've overwritten your PATH, restart terminal to have it fixed.

Answer (score 3):

I know it's super frustrating and some what confusing to get this all to work. Been there, done that.

There are a couple things at play here, so take them one at a time (in fact. I'm just guessing some stuff so I'm happy to update this answer as you let me know more)

Let's start with:

`Warning: Experimental support for using Xcode without the "Command Line Tools". You have only installed Xcode. If stuff is not building, try installing the "Command Line Tools" package provided by Apple.`

Installing command line tools is highly recommended. It's going to install gcc and other tools that help compile the code that homebrew downloads.

1. Open Xcode.
2. Open Preferences.
3. On the top bar, choose "Downloads"
4. Install "Command line tools"

Second, I'm not sure how you quite blew away your path. I would first see if you just messed up this terminal and if you close it and start a new terminal window if your PATH is okay.

However, failing that, here's a path that has some basic search paths that will help you get on your way:

`export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/sbin`

You should probably check your .zshrc/.zsh_profile or .bashrc/.bash_profile and see what you are setting your PATH to.

You won't want the space on either side of the `=` when you are typing that command.

Answer (score -1):

I recently tried the upgrade from 10.6 to 10.8 (to install rails, bundler, RVM) and had lots of the same problems with brew and RVM conflicting AND having their own separate problems (PATH, permissions/non-writable folders, old versions XCode etc).  It went off without problems after i tripled backed up everything (TMachine, git and manually copying selected directory trees) and did the clean Mountain Lion install off a USB drive.

If you're only having PATH problems, you could edit it manually/temporarily (until next time .bashrc is run, per comment to the answer: [Brew doctor gives out warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15225312/brew-doctor-gives-out-warnings)